# How to capture the value of a cell of a TableViewer where a contextual menu has been activated in eclipse e4?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

In one of my eclipse e4 application [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox), some data is displayed in a`TableViewer`
A contextual menu is defined in the e4 model file (`e4xmi`) and linked to the`TableViewer` like this

```java
menuService.registerContextMenu(tableViwere.getTable(), <name of the e4 part menu>);
```

Attached to the contextual menu in the e4 model, a "menu item" is linked to a`"Dynamic Menu Contribution"` class that dynamically add the menu items to the menu:

```java
public class VisualizerShowPayloadAsMenu {
   @Inject private EModelService       modelService;
   @AboutToShow
   public void aboutToShow(EModelService modelService, List<MMenuElement> items) {
      // Not the real code..., illustrate adding a dynamic menu item to the contextual menu
      MDirectMenuItem dynamicItem = modelService.createModelElement(MDirectMenuItem.class);
      dynamicItem.setLabel(<name..>);
      dynamicItem.setContributorURI(Constants.BASE_CORE_PLUGIN);// "platform:/plugin/org.titou10.jtb.core");
      dynamicItem.setContributionURI(Constants.VISUALIZER_MENU_URI);// "bundleclass://org.titou10.jtb.core/org.titou10.jtb.visualizer.ui.VisualizerShowPayloadAsHandler");
      items.add(dynamicItem);
   }
```

Now, what I want to do is to capture the data in the underlying cell where the contextual menu has been activated, and get that value back in the method annotated by`"@AboutToShow"` in order
to add`MDirectMenuItem`entries to the contextual menu with a label containing that value
Q: how to do that with eclipse rcp e4?

In the attached picture, the right click happened in the cell with content=`"ID:414d5120514d41414544202020202020ee4bb25612666920"`. I would like to get this value back in the `@AboutToShow`method and add menu items to the`"Open Payload as..."`menu based on that value
Thanks

[image]

Comment: @greg, you've deleted your anser. no problem with that but you also deleted my second comment. So, what I'm thinking about is to capture the right clicked event in a cell, get the text shown in the cell and store the value in the eclipse context. This could be injected later in the`@AboutToShow` method. The question is what listener wiil give access to the cell content? `CellEditor`? a`FocusListenr`? Something else? WDYT?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to determine which cell the mouse was on when the context menu was invoked - the cell generally won't have focus. EditingSupport is for allowing the current cell to be edited it isn't involved in context menu display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it!
I'm not sure it is the best way, but at least it works and it is quite simple

The following code is here to illustrate the idea, it is not valid Java. 
In the part that manage the`TableViewer`:

```
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
{...}
new TableViewerFocusCellManager(tableViewer, new JTBFocusCellHighlighter(tableViewer, windowContext));
```

`JTBFocusCellHighlighter`class:

```
public class JTBFocusCellHighlighter extends FocusCellHighlighter {
   private IEclipseContext windowContext;
   private Table           table;
   public JTBFocusCellHighlighter(ColumnViewer viewer, IEclipseContext windowContext) {
      super(viewer);
      this.windowContext = windowContext;
      this.table = ((TableViewer) viewer).getTable();
   }
   @Override
   protected void focusCellChanged(ViewerCell newCell, ViewerCell oldCell) {
      super.focusCellChanged(newCell, oldCell);
      // Capture the content of the cell (or other info..) and store it in Eclipse Context
      windowContext.set("key", newCell.getText());
      TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumn(newCell.getColumnIndex());
   }
}
```

Real code implementation: [JTBSessionContentViewPart](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.core/src/org/titou10/jtb/ui/part/content/JTBSessionContentViewPart.java)  , [JTBFocusCellHighlighter](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.core/src/org/titou10/jtb/ui/part/content/JTBFocusCellHighlighter.java)  and [FilterMenu](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.core/src/org/titou10/jtb/selectors/FilterMenu.java)